# Change working directory to network share

Tags: cmd.exe, shared-folders

I can list all files in a folder with:
`dir \\aenw08v401\FOLDER\I001\*`

However, when I execute `cd \\aenw08v401\FOLDER\I001`, the current working directory won't change at all.

This is what I see when I execute `net view \\aenw08v401`:

```
Shared resources at \\aenw08v401
Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-----------------------------------
FOLDER    Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

Is there a switch I am missing, or do I need to use a different command?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Windows command prompt `cmd` does not support UNC paths as current directories.

```
C:\Users\User1>cd \\myServer\myShare
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

**Solution:** Use `pushd`.

```
C:\Users\User1>pushd \\myServer\myShare

Z:\>dir
 Volume in drive Z is MYDRIVE
 Volume Serial Number is 1234-5678

 Directory of Z:\

12/16/2015  11:18 AM    <DIR>          .
12/16/2015  11:18 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  120,609,575,936 bytes free

Z:\>popd

C:\Users\User1>
```

**Alternate Solution:** Map the UNC path to a drive letter.

```
C:\Users\User1>net use Y: \\myServer\myShare 
The command completed successfully.

C:\Users\User1>Y:

Y:\>dir
 Volume in drive Y is MYDRIVE
 Volume Serial Number is 1234-5678

 Directory of Y:\

12/16/2015  11:18 AM    <DIR>          .
12/16/2015  11:18 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  120,609,575,936 bytes free

Y:\>C:

C:\Users\User1>net use /delete Y:
Y: was deleted successfully.
```

Comment: The pushd solution worked perfectly for me, though in the end `psexec` worked out better for me

Comment: Or use PowerShell where `cd \\Server\path` just works.

Comment: I first tried the second one, it worked like magic.